Value change from db when called by api
I'm experiencing an issue with retrieving data from my database through an API call.
I have a table in my database where the id column contains alphanumeric values, which are mechanographic codes for the institutes in Turin. When I query the database directly, I see the correct values in the id column. However, when I fetch the data through an API call on my front end, the id values are all changed to 0.
Here are the details of my setup:
Backend: Laravel 11 (API only) with Breeze
Frontend: Vue.js
API Calls: Made using Axios
Example of a record from the database:
id: TOIC86200P
name: LC Vittorio Alfieri
created_at: 2024-07-08 14:54:41
updated_at: 2024-07-08 14:54:41

Example of the same record fetched via API:
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "LC Vittorio Alfieri",
    "created_at": "2024-07-08T14:54:41.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-07-08T14:54:41.000000Z"
}

As you can see, the id value becomes 0 in the API response.
I'm looking for help to identify where this discrepancy is occurring and how to resolve it. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Verified the API Controller: I checked the controller method that retrieves the data to ensure there are no transformations or alterations of the id value. The method looks straightforward and directly fetches the record by its ID.
Institute.php (model)
class Institute extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'id',
    ];
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class); 
    }
}

also my migration file for the Institutes table is like this:
        <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::create('institutes', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('id')->primary(); 
                $table->string('name'); 
    
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down(): void
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('institutes');
        }
    };



and my controller use json as response:
class InstituteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $institutes = Institute::select('id', 'name', 'code')->get();

        return response()->json(['institutes' => $institutes], 200);
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        $institute = institute::findOrFail($id);

        return response()->json(['institute' => $institute], 200);
    }

}


What data type you assigned for id in DB migration? Share your migration file.

Which type of response do you use to return the data? Do you use Resources?

my migratio file for the table institute is like this:`

provided migrations and controller

If you are wondering what 'code' is:
I managed to correctly retrieve the mechanographic code by defining it in both the model and the migration as a separate parameter (code). In this case, although the API still sets all my id values to 0, the code value is as expected.
I know that code is not defined in the migration I provided earlier. This is because I sent you an older version of the file. Defining code separately was just a workaround, and I don't want to keep it this way.

I think the issue is that you're using a non-numeric value as the primary key. You might need to set some properties in your model to handle that.
According to the Laravel official documentation -

If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must define a public $incrementing property on your model that is set to false.


If your model's primary key is not an integer, you should define a protected $keyType property on your model. This property should have a value of string

Link to the docs
I think this will solve your problem.
